# RxJS Observable with Subject, polling via timer and combineLatest does not fire

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, polling, rxjs5

I wrote a function to do polling on an API that is also able to do pagination. Herefor the pagination is done using a Subject Observable and polling is done with the timer method (I also tried interval with the same result).

Here is my code:

```
  getItems(pagination: Subject<Pagination>): Observable<ListResult<Item>> {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    return Observable
      .timer(0, 5000)
      .combineLatest(
        pagination,
        (timer, pagination) => pagination
      )
      .startWith({offset: 0, limit: 3})
      .switchMap(pagination => {
        params.set('skip', pagination.offset.toString());
        params.set('limit', pagination.limit.toString());
        return this.authHttp.get(`${environment.apiBase}/items`, {search: params})
      })
      .map(response => response.json() as ListResult<Item>)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

The expected behavior would be:
HTTP request is fired every 5 seconds AND when the user changes the page.

This is what happens:
First HTTP request is fired, but then no other request is sent to the server UNTIL pagination is used. 
After pagination is used the first time, the polling starts working too.

It's the first time I'm using Observables so I'm pretty sure I missed something, but I can't see what it might be.

I also tried this approach (maybe it was missing the timer counter in startWith), but it didn't change anything.

```
[...]
  .combineLatest(
    pagination
  )
  .startWith([0, {offset: 0, limit: 3}])
[...]
```

Comment: combineLatest only works once both observables have emitted once, [play with the RxJS marbles to see](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html). I'm thinking maybe your `startsWith` needs to be applied to pagination before  being combined with the timer.

Comment: That's what martin suggested in his solution (and you're both right).
I was aware of that combineLatest does wait for all observables, but I somehow thought that startWith would kickstart both Observables automatically. I was wrong ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `combineLatest()` operator requires all source Observables to emit at least one item.

Your demo makes only one request because you're using `.startWith()`. The `combineLatest()` never emits because the `pagination` is a `Subject` and it probably never emits any item.

So one option is to move `.startWith()`:

```
.combineLatest(
  pagination.startWith({offset: 0, limit: 3}),
  (timer, pagination) => pagination
)
```

But maybe this doesn't help you much because you're ignoring all items coming from the `timer()` and you're using just `pagination`. So maybe you could use just `merge()` to refresh the list from one of the sources. Then the `timer()` independently increases the offset.

```
Observable
  .timer(0, 1000)
  .map(i => { return {offset: i*3, limit: 3}})
  .merge(pagination.startWith({offset: 0, limit: 3}))
  .switchMap(pagination => {
    return Observable.of(pagination).delay(200)
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Your first answer worked!
I just moved startWith to the pagination Subject Observable and it worked. 

When I used startWith in my solution the timer actually worked, but the pagination Obersable was never fired and combineLatest stayed waiting.


A clever and easy solution.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are following below steps

#### Creating Observable Data

You have an Observable variable and you are pushing data by `observable.next(value);`

#### Putting data into a Subject or Behavior Subject

Where you want to get the data you are declaring a Subject type variable and access it by subscribing to it.

```
private val: Subject = YourObservable;
private uiValue: string;

val.subscribe((val) => {
   uiVal = val;
});
```

Now you can use the uiVal anywhere which will update in each inteval.

You can test both the pieces separately by just making the `console.log` to make sure everything is working fine.

Comment: As I wrote in the description I used both with the same result

Comment: I tried it a second ago. Sadly didn't change anything

Comment: @Gesh Edited the answer, make sure you are doing everything correct in observable.next and then subscribe side